# Check name inside marque

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code I want to detect name from marque if  click button that contain name from marquee maybe the text (score) increase by 1 but I'm begin to check with alert
I tried in **You button** to add function

[Demo and code](https://posttoall.blogspot.com/2021/04/simple.html#)

Comment: The text is generated by javascript, why can't you store current text in a variable, which you can later access from another part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `marquee.innerText` instead of `marquee.value`:

```js
var  greetings = [ "You", 
"Me", 
"Ben", 
"I", 
"You", 
"Biz", 
"We", 
"He / She / It", 
"O", 
"Onlar"


];

var msecs = 2000; //Milliseconds that will wait to change the text
var marq = document.getElementById("marq"); //The object
var pix = marq.clientWidth; //The width in the screen

//You have to vary this... If you know a little bit of maths they can help you.
marq.scrollAmount = (pix / (msecs / 50));

setInterval(function() 
{
    var greeting_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * greetings.length);
    document.getElementById('textme').innerHTML = greetings[greeting_id];
}, msecs);


function GameChecked(){
        var text = document.getElementsByName("Phone")[0].innerText;
        if(text == "sen" || text == "Ben" || text == "They" || text == "Biz" || text == "I"  ) {
           alert("Ok");
                  
        }
        
        else{
            alert("Correct solution: You");
            
            
  
        }
    }
```

```html
<marquee id="marq" name="Phone" direction="down" width="350" height="300" behavior="alternate" style="border:2px solid red">
  <marquee behavior="alternate">

  
  <div id="textme"></div></marquee></marquee>
  

  
 

<br>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame" onclick="GameChecked()">You</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">Sen</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">Ben</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">They</a>
<br><br>

<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">Biz</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">Onlar</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">We</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">O</a>
<br><br>

<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">I</a>
<a href="#" class="myButtonGame">He / She / It</a>
```

Comment: thanks so so so so so so so so so so so so so so so so so so so so MUCH